# Libtorrent set upload/download limit before download starts

Tags: python, bittorrent, torrent, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I want to set the upload/download limit before the start of download.
For ex. in the current way I am setting download/upload limit like this:

```
info = lt.torrent_info(ft['torrent_info'])
params = { 'save_path': '.', \
         'storage_mode': lt.storage_mode_t.storage_mode_sparse, \
         'ti': info }
h = ses.add_torrent(params)
h.set_download_limit(10000)
h.set_upload_limit(10000)
```

But in this case during `h = ses.add_torrent(params)`, download is getting started and I am setting upload/download speed after this. So here for some time my download/upload speed will be very high.
I want to set download/upload limit before this step(before my download begins). Can I do that ? May be setting some parameters in params dict. ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Take a look at the [`add_torrent_params`](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#add_torrent_params) object.

There are two fields, [upload_limit and download](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#upload_limit) limit, that initialize the limits.

Comment: Hey @Arvind. I tried by setting download/upload limit but still not getting success. I posted question for that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045564/libtorrent-setting-download-limit-upload-limit-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Do you read this manual: http://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#add_torrent_params ?

You may try to set these flags: `flag_stop_when_ready` or `flag_paused`.

Comment: Hey @Serenity: I am still facing issues while setting download/upload limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045564/libtorrent-setting-download-limit-upload-limit-is-not-working