# Libtorrent setting download_limit/upload_limit is not working

Tags: python, bittorrent, torrent, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I want to rate limit my download/upload speed in my libtorrent client. I am using the following code for this.

```
params = { 'save_path': '.', \
           'storage_mode': lt.storage_mode_t.storage_mode_sparse, \
           'ti': info, 'flags': 0x020 }

h = ses.add_torrent(params)
h.set_download_limit(100)
h.set_upload_limit(100)
h.resume()
```

It should download the data at 0.1 kb/sec, but still it is downloading the data at the speed of around 1500 kb/sec.

```
100.00% complete (down: 1576.0 kb/s up: 55.0 kB/s)
```

Anything I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your peers are on the same local network as yourself. By default, local peers are not subject to the rate limit (as documented [here](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#download_rate_limit)).

Unfortunately the documentation on how to make rate limits apply to local peers is a bit lacking. I've tried to remedy that in this [pull request](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/pull/1859).

Basically, to make the global rate limit apply to all peers, regardless of which IP they have, do this:

```
std::uint32_t const mask = 1 << lt::session::global_peer_class_id;
ip_filter f;

// for every IPv4 address, assign the global peer class
f.add_rule(address_v4::from_string("0.0.0.0")
    , address_v4::from_string("255.255.255.255")
    , mask);

// for every IPv6 address, assign the global peer class
f.add_rule(address_v6::from_string("::")
    , address_v6::from_string("ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff")
    , mask);
ses.set_peer_class_filter(f);
```

Comment: Can you suggest syntax for python. I am not able to find anything for that.

Comment: I have tried, g=lt.ip_filter(), g.add_rule("0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255",0), and then started. There is no set_peer_class_filter method in handle or lt.session(). I have tried ses.set_ip_filter(g), but still no success.

Comment: I have tried ses.set_local_download_rate_limit(10000) also. No success even in this case.

Comment: Hey finally its working, but with some weird workarounds. When I am doing ses.set_local_upload_rate_limit(10000) and ses.set_local_download_rate_limit(10000), it is still downloading at same speed(around 1500 kb/sec). But when I am adding h.set_download_limit(10) and h.set_upload_limit(10), the rate limit starts working(with local peers at 10 kb/sec). Another weird thing is, when I am putting any arguments >=5 to h.set_download_limit() and h.set_upload_limit(), its working fine. But when I am giving argument less than 5 i.e. =1, the download speed stays at 0.

Comment: any idea about the above behavior ?